# Register one keystroke on element call

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm building a Gutenberg block, and in my editor block I've got a text-based (p, h2...) element with contenteditable set as true, it's got a callback of `onInput`, when any keystroke is pressed it calls the function I've linked to it.  This is working as I'd like it to but for every keypress the cursor is moved to the start of the text.

I've tried to set a timer but it just means all of the keystroke functions are delayed by however long I set.

I would like to be able to cut the calls down to a single call, or alternatively if there is a known way to not have the cursor position be reset whenever I update the content that would also be great.

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'arttastic/about-block', {
    title: 'About Block',
    icon: 'info',
    category: 'design',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'Title'
        },
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'content'
        },
        img: {
            type: 'image'
        },
        btn_text: {
            type: 'text',
            default: 'Button'
        },
        btn_link: {
            type: 'url',
            default: 'https://www.amias.dev'
        }
    },
    edit: function(props) {

        let updateAttr = ( event, attr ) => {

            props.setAttributes( { [attr]: event.target.innerText } );
        }

        // return htmlEl( gutenbergEditor() );
        return gutenbergEditor( props, updateAttr );
    },
    save: function(props) {

        return frontEnd( props );
    }
});

let gutenbergEditor = ( props, updateAttr ) => {
    return React.createElement( 'div', null, 
        React.createElement( 'h2', {
            contenteditable: 'true',
            onInput: e => {
                setTimeout( updateAttr, 5000, e, 'title' );
            }
        }, props.attributes.title ),
        React.createElement( 'p', {
            contenteditable: 'true',
            onInput: e => {
                updateAttr( e, 'content' );
            }
        }, props.attributes.content ),
        React.createElement( 'p', {
            contenteditable: 'true',
            onInput: e => {
                updateAttr( e, 'button_text' );
            }
        }, props.attributes.button_text )
    );
}
```

Comment: You could consider using the [`RichText`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/richtext/) component built in to WordPress core via `wp.blockEditor` from the `wp-block-editor` script. This component could be an alternative choice that handles `contenteditable` elements for you that has already been battle-tested extensively.